# WiX Installer removes shortcut on upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I am using the WiX Toolkit v3.11 for creating setups of my software. During installation I create startmenu shortcuts with the following code:

```
<Shortcut Id='startmenuMyProgram'
          Name='$(var.MyProgramName)'
          Directory='ProgramMenuFolder'
          WorkingDirectory='APPLICATIONFOLDER'
          Advertise='yes'
          Icon='icon.exe'>
  <Icon Id='icon.exe' SourceFile='$(var.Setuppath)\MyProgram.exe'/>
</Shortcut>
```

In this way I also create two shortcuts for other executables. Now for the uninstall I want to remove the shortcuts.

```
<Component Id="removeStartmenuShortcuts" Guid="803ad14a-feab-4901-b9db-2c4a1298ae8b">
  <Condition>(REMOVE=ALL) AND NOT (WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)</Condition>

  <RemoveFile Id="remove_startmenuProgram1" Name="startmenuMyProgram" On="uninstall" />
  <RemoveFile Id="remove_startmenuProgram2" Name="startmenuMyProgram2" On="uninstall"/>
  <RemoveFile Id="remove_startmenuProgram3" Name="startmenuMyProgram3" On="uninstall"/>
</Component>
```

This works without any problems when I uninstall the software. But the shortcuts are also removed when an update is performed. But I want to prevent this behavior, but the condition seems not to work. So all shortcuts like in the Windows task bar are removed when I do an update.

How can I make my update progress work correctly?

Here the behavior after update:

[image: Behavior when doing an update]

The group with all shortcuts in the right is missing!

Comment: Check verbose log if the properties you are checking for in the component condition, have the values you expect. Enable verbose log like this: `msiexec.exe -i yoursetup.msi -l*v logfile.txt`

Comment: The properties are all how I expect it:

Property(N): REMOVE = ALL

Property(N): UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE = {A865F4E4-D7EF-4D29-A713-242DB35CBE1A}

Property(S): WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED = {22AA6027-9FDF-4637-BEE5-CAE8D5E2AA46}

Comment: It just came to my mind that the shortcuts will of course be removed on uninstall/upgrade if you install them through a `<Shortcut>` element. That's just normal windows installer behaviour, you don't even need a `<RemoveFile>` element for that. Actually I don't understand the problem at all. Normally your update install would just reinstall the same shortcuts.

Comment: When I move the shortcut from the left side of the Windows 10 startmenu to the right side and do an update, the shortcut on the right side disappeares. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I still don't get why you think that you need the `removeStartmenuShortcuts` component with the explicit `<RemoveFile>` elements. All shortcuts that your installer has created will automatically be removed upon uninstall. The only thing you may have to explicitly remove is the shortcut *folder*, as shown in [this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the 2 component. By this you will not need to use condition statements.

The registry value is to set a keypath under component.

```
  <Component Id="cmpstartmenuMyProgram" Guid="{67CB4F7A-5028-4697-A47F-DE99110B9645}">
    <Shortcut Id="Shortcut.ApplicationName"
              Name="ApplicationName"
              Target="[INSTALLDIR]ApplicationName.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
              Directory="StartMenuFolder"
              Icon="Icon.exe"/>
    <RemoveFile Id="RemoveStartMenuShortcut.ApplicationName" Name="ApplicationName" Directory="StartMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Compony\ComponyName" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
```